# Contextual ActionBar to multiselect items in a custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

How do you implement a contextual action bar for a custom list view to select multiple list items?

I want my application to be similar to the **Contacts application in Samsung Mobiles**.

When scrolling through the **Contacts List**, clicking `Menu -> Delete` adds checkboxes to each list item and a temporary overlay appears over the actionbar.

Could someone help with some pointers on where to begin with this?

As I'm using custom list using custom layout and adapter, there is no scope to use `listview.setChoiceMode();`

Answer (score 2):

You must use a contextual menu bar, take a look at these tutorials:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-a-contextual-menu-bar-contextual-action-mode-for-a-listview-in-android/#comment-84075

http://androidperspective.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/contextual-action-bar-with-listview/